# Pass ASP.NET authentication ticket to & from Appcelerator Mobile App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Looking to integrate a login page in an Appcelerator mobile app with ASP.NET membership.

A particular aspect I am looking at is how to keep the user logged in between mobile app sessions, i.e. after closing and re-opening the mobile app the user is still logged in

Ideally the process would go as follows

1. User enters login details to mobile app
2. Mobile app passes details to ASP.NET site
3. Site signs user in, and returns authentication cookie
4. Mobile app stores authentication cookie locally
5. For each mobile app site request, it passes the authentication cookie to the site
6. User logs out, clear local authentication cookie

Thinking because it is a mobile app, best to return data as a json object, for example,

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)) {
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
  var json = new {
    success = true,
    username = username,
    message = "Logged In",
    authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]
};
return serializer.Serialize(json);
```

Is this process possible or should I be looking at a different solution?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please refer to the following links for ideas of how to implement http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/63731/web-login--register-example and http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/90751/how-to-deal-with-sessions-and-login

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your login page after the user is validated (after calling `Membership.ValidateUser()`):

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
  FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, true
);
```

[It's documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kuujinbo. I think in this instance, the FormsAuthentication cookie will need to be passed as a json object back to the mobile app not a URL ... I think?

Comment: @SeanDooley - My bad. I read your question as one of those "*Help get me started...*" with respect to **both** ASP.NET membership and Appcelerator. Looking at your edit, I can see that's not the case specifically with regard to ASP.NET membership. Sorry I can't be of more help...